# Automatic image reload only for once: javascript or html

Tags: reload

How can a specific image embedded in my page using an img tag be automatically (ie. without user input/action) reloaded only for once using javascript and/or html, once the page has been loaded completely? And I would like the image to be reloaded from the source location, not the browser cache. Plz be a bit lucid.

Answer (score 1):

You can append a dummy URL parameter on the `IMAGE` element source. For example, if the image URL is `http://mysite.com/image.jpg`, change it to `http://mysite.com/image.jpg?dummy`. If the image URL already has some parameters on it like `http://mysite.com/image.jpg?varname=VarValue`, change it to `http://mysite.com/image.jpg?varname=VarValue&dummy`. Usually, the dummy parameter is the current time as numbers.

Here's an example code using time as the dummy parameter. It'll change the image URL to something like `http://mysite.com/image.jpg?1347218169148`. The function will be executed after the page is loaded and will process all `IMAGE` elements.

```
<script>
onload = function() {
  var i, imgs = document.images;
  for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].src += (imgs[i].src.indexOf('?') < 0 ? '?' : '&') + (new Date()).valueOf();
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot change the image url at source since the image is in another domain of which I have no control. What can I do in this situation? Secondly, can I place the function inside the body tag to be triggered by onLoad there, like this : `<body onload="function();"`? Finally, what if I use `<script>window.onload=function() {...}</script>` or `<script>window.onload="function();"</script>` right before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: Your original question said that the image is placed in your page using an `IMAGE` tag. That won't violate cross domain restriction since the `IMAGE` tag is in your own page, in your own domain. That code can be placed anywhere since the actual function execution will be done after the page is loaded. If placed in the `BODY` tag's `ONLOAD` attribute, it should be `onload="(function(){/*the function codes*/})();"`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Jay! Working perfectly.